# how to delete several items simultaneously from a ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I'm having trouble with a homework, the thing is I have around 40.000 `HashMap<Character,Character>` objects stored in a `ArrayList<HashMap<Character,Character>>`object.

Each object `HashMap<Character,Character>` object represent a key for a substitution cipher. So one HashMap object might be: `a->a; b->b; c->c; d->d; e->e; f->f; g->h; h->g`
which means that the g and h are swapped during encription/decryption.

The problem is that I'm coding a brute force attack on this cipher, so I'm looping over those 40.000 keys.

When the program detects that say g->h It's a wrong substitution, I want to delete all the HashMap objects that contain this entry, not only the current element that I'm working with inside the loop and thus be able to avoid checking the keys one by one.

So far I've tried the following, but its getting stuck no exception or anything just doesnt finish, not even while debugging:

```
  ArrayList<HashMap<Character,Character>> all_keys = new ...`
  all_keys = generateAllCombinations();`
  ArrayList<HashMap<Character,Character>> keys_to_delete = new ...`

  for(HashMap<Character,Character> key:all_keys){`
     all_keys.removeAll(keys_to_delete);
     \\other stuff going on...`
        if (!letters[0].getChar().equals(Constants.CHAR_E)){
         Character invChar = key.get(Constants.CHAR_E);
          for(HashMap<Character,Character> key2 : all_keys){
                if(key2.get(Constants.CHAR_E).equals(invChar)){
                 keys_to_delete.add(key2);
                }
          }

    }
   }
```

Comment: You might want to step up the design and use real objects, maybe introduce a `Substitution` (2 `char` fields `from`, `to`), then you will be working on a list of `Substitution`. Back to your problem, you're modifying a collection you're iteration on and that is forbidden and throws a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: Actually, you can modify a collection you are working on, *if* you use an Iterator instead of a foreach loop, using iter.remove().  But that still won't let you do a removeAll().

Answer (score 0):

Use Iterator. My Solution is working but may be it requires tuning for performance.

```
   Iterator<Map<String,String>> all_keys_iterator = all_keys.iterator();
   List<Map<String,String>> all_keys_new = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>> ();

   while(all_keys_iterator.hasNext()) {
    Map<String,String> copyMap = new HashMap<String,String> ();

    Map<String,String> all_keys_map = all_keys_iterator.next();
    for(String key: all_keys_map.keySet()) {
        if (!key.equalsIgnoreCase("key1")){
            copyMap.put(key, all_keys_map.get(key));
        }
    }
    if(!copyMap.isEmpty()) {
        all_keys_iterator.remove();
        all_keys_new.add(copyMap);
    }                      
   }

   all_keys.addAll(all_keys_new);

   for(Map<String,String> map: all_keys) {
    for(String key: map.keySet()) {
        System.out.println("key: " + key + " Value: " + map.get(key));
    }
   }
```

Comment: I think he wants to remove the current hashmap, plus all other hashmaps which contain the same mapping.

Comment: @azurefrog That's right, I want to remove several hashmap elements.

Answer (score 0):

It was lready mentioned that you have to be careful when removing elements from a collection that you are currently iterating over. This may easily cause a `ConcurrentModificationException`. For "complicated" cases where you can not easily use an iterator, a pattern that can often be applied is that instead of doing something like

```
Collection<Element> collection = ...
for (Element element : collection)
{
    if (hasToBeRemoved(element)) 
    {
        // Will cause a ConcurrentModificationException!
        collection.remove(element);
    }
}
```

you collect the elements to be removed, and remove them all at once

```
Collection<Element> collection = ...
Collection<Element> elementsToRemove = new List<Element>();
for (Element element : collection)
{
    if (hasToBeRemoved(element)) 
    {
        elementsToRemove.add(element);
    }
}
collection.removeAll(elementsToRemove);
```

According to the code, you seem to have tried something similar, with your `keys_to_delete`, but that's not entirely clear.

And as mentioned in the comment, you should consider dedicated data structures for the substitutions etc. But even if you wish to stick to Lists and Maps for this purpose, you should *always* use the *interface* in the declarations. So instead of

```
ArrayList<HashMap<Character,Character>> allKeys = ...
```

you should write

```
List<Map<Character,Character>> allKeys = ...
```

---

However, regarding the actual question: It seems like the main issue can be resolved by introducing a method like `computeKeysContaining(maps, entry)` that returns all maps from a given collection that contain a certain entry.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class MapListKeyRemoval
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Map<Character,Character>> allKeys = generateAllCombinations();

        print("All keys", allKeys);

        Set<Map<Character,Character>> keysToDelete = 
            new LinkedHashSet<Map<Character,Character>>();
        for (Map<Character, Character> key : allKeys)
        {
            for (Entry<Character, Character> entry : key.entrySet())
            {
                if (isInvalidMapping(entry))
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid mapping: "+entry);
                    Set<Map<Character, Character>> keysWithInvalidMapping =
                        computeKeysContaining(allKeys, entry);

                    print("Keys with invalid mapping", keysWithInvalidMapping);

                    keysToDelete.addAll(keysWithInvalidMapping);
                }
            }
        }
        print("Keys to delete", keysToDelete);

        allKeys.removeAll(keysToDelete);

        print("All keys after removal", allKeys);
    }

    private static void print(
        String message, Iterable<Map<Character,Character>> keys)
    {
        System.out.println(message);
        for (Map<Character, Character> key : keys)
        {
            System.out.println(key);
        }
    }

    private static Set<Map<Character, Character>> computeKeysContaining(
        List<Map<Character,Character>> allKeys,
        Entry<Character, Character> entry)
    {
        Set<Map<Character,Character>> keysContainingEntry =  
            new LinkedHashSet<Map<Character,Character>>();
        for (Map<Character, Character> key : allKeys)
        {
            Object value = key.get(entry.getKey());
            if (value != null && value.equals(entry.getValue()))
            {
                keysContainingEntry.add(key);
            }
        }
        return keysContainingEntry;
    }

    private static boolean isInvalidMapping(Entry<Character, Character> entry)
    {
        return entry.getKey().equals('g') && entry.getValue().equals('h');
    }

    private static List<Map<Character, Character>> generateAllCombinations()
    {
        List<Map<Character, Character>> result = 
            new ArrayList<Map<Character,Character>>();
        result.add(createMapping('f','i','r','s','t','-','g','h'));
        result.add(createMapping('s','e','c','o','n','d','g','x'));
        result.add(createMapping('t','h','i','r','d','-','g','h'));
        result.add(createMapping('f','o','u','r','t','h','g','x'));
        return result;
    }

    private static Map<Character, Character> createMapping(char ... c)
    {
        Map<Character, Character> map = 
            new LinkedHashMap<Character, Character>();
        for (int i=0; i<c.length/2; i++)
        {
            map.put(c[i*2+0], c[i*2+1]);
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```